# Errors C2512 & C3892 - Building PacMan like game

Tags: c++, variables, constructor, constants, default-constructor

I am relatively new to programming so please bear this in mind.
I am currently building a 2D PacMan like game in C++ but I am getting the above errors. I am trying to implement some zombies in to my game which I have declared as an 'Item' with an array to represent the max amount of zombies allowed in the game. Here are some samples of my code (this has been cut down to just show the limited parts of the zombie code):

```
const char ZOMBIE('Z');
const int MAXZOMBIES(4);

int main()
{
    Item zombies[MAXZOMBIES];
    int numZombies(4);
}

void setZombiesInitialCoordinates(Item zombies[])
{
    //Setting zombie coordinates for top left of grid
    zombies[0].symbol = ZOMBIE;
    zombies[0].x = (SIZEX - 19);
    zombies[0].y = (SIZEY - 11);

    //Setting zombie coordinates for top right of grid
    zombies[1].symbol = ZOMBIE;
    zombies[1].x = (SIZEX - 2);
    zombies[1].y = (SIZEY - 11);

    //Setting zombie coordinates for bottom left of grid
    zombies[2].symbol = ZOMBIE;
    zombies[2].x = (SIZEX - 19);
    zombies[2].y = (SIZEY - 2);

    //Setting zombie coordinates for bottom right of grid
    zombies[3].symbol = ZOMBIE;
    zombies[3].x = (SIZEX - 2);
    zombies[3].y = (SIZEY - 2);
}
```

The whole code can be viewed on pastebin if this would make things easier: http://pastebin.com/1kFTD2Mr

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Do you actually believe that every C++ compiler for every operating system in the world uses the same error code for every compilation error?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: He did say he is relatively new to programming...

Comment: @KieranW: Do you know which lines _exactly_ are causing the errors?

Comment: Not immediately relevant, but have a look at std::vector, and std::list for storing your zombies. Perhaps std::map too if the Zombies are uniquely identifiable.

Comment: You're trying to assign to something that is declared `const`. Since that thing is a member, it is the source of both errors. (You don't need to declare your functions inside every function that uses them - have you seen *anyone* do this, ever? Once, at the top of the file, is enough.)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the relevant class definition:

```
struct Item {
        const char symbol;
        int x, y;
};
```

and the error messages:

```
C2512: no appropriate default constructor available
C3892: you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

`symbol` is `const` so, as the second error message says, you can't assign to it. A `const` member also prevents default construction, since that would give no way to give the member a valid value; hence the first error.

You could remove the `const`; or, if you want to keep it, you'll have to initialise the items with their values, rather than assigning to them after initialisation:

```
Item zombies[] = {
    {ZOMBIE, SIZEX - 19, SIZEY - 11},
    {ZOMBIE, SIZEX -  2, SIZEY - 11},
    {ZOMBIE, SIZEX - 19, SIZEY -  2},
    {ZOMBIE, SIZEX -  2, SIZEY -  2}
};
```